# Flutter : "Could not resolved the package" every install new packages

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some problem about installing new package from pub.dev. I create my own package inside my root project with this command :

`flutter create --template=package main_template`

### structure folder

[image: Structure folder]

I installing new package inside **main_template** not **lib**. every install new package in **main_template** i received this error :

```
Compiler message:
Error: Could not resolve the package 'device_info' in 'package:device_info/device_info.dart'.
sinergi_flutter_template/main_template/lib/variable/get_device_id.dart:3:8: Error: Not found: 'package:device_info/device_info.dart'
import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';
       ^
sinergi_flutter_template/main_template/lib/variable/get_device_id.dart:9:11: Error: 'DeviceInfoPlugin' isn't a type.
    final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sinergi_flutter_template/main_template/lib/variable/get_device_id.dart:9:47: Error: The method 'DeviceInfoPlugin' isn't defined for the class 'GetDeviceId'.
 - 'GetDeviceId' is from 'package:main_template/variable/get_device_id.dart' ('sinergi_flutter_template/main_template/lib/variable/get_device_id.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'DeviceInfoPlugin'.
    final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
U
nhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-u
ntranslatable-uri:package%3Adevice_info%2Fdevice_info.dart; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri  (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)
#1      asFileUri ( (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:604:3)
7)
#2      writeDepfile  (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:799:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile  (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:472:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (package:flut
ter_frontend_server/server.dart:38:22)
#5      starter  (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:149:27)
#6      main  (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:8:30)
#7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure>  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:305:32)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

> Until now i trying install 3 package [Cache Network Image,Device Info , SplashScreen]. And all packages give me that error.

How can i fixed it ?

Comment: Have you added the packages to your pubspec file and run `flutter pub get`?

Comment: Don't put flutter projects inside other flutter projects. They should be siblings; you'll have your app and package at the same level under, say, `projects`. In the pubspec of one, refer to the other with `path: ../other`.

Comment: @Abion47 after run `flutter pub get` everything is works!. I think with `flutter packages get` it's enough, but after follow your comment is works.

Comment: @Richard Heap so my `main_template` should be outside of my root project?

Comment: yes, because then you can reuse it in a future project.

Answer (score 16):

Are you using vs code?

just restart or close the vs code app (all window), then open it again an run

flutter pub get

Answer (score 8):

This command fixed my issue:

> flutter pub get

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Android Studio?

Then just restart it. Worked for me.

Make sure you already have run:

> flutter pub get

Answer (score 4):

It's a very annoying issue caused by the pubspec.**lock** file.

When you add a dependency lower in your package hierarchy you need to confirm it's added to the main app's pubspec.lock file.

It won't be added automatically so:

1. Navigate to the main app's pubspec.lock file folder
2. Run "flutter pub get"
3. Check the pubspec.lock file to confirm your dependency is there
4. If not run "flutter clean" and then repeat **step 2**

No need to clean the cache or anything :)

Answer (score 3):

try this command

> flutter clean

and then pub get

try this command incase if u face any cache related issue

> flutter pub cache repair

Answer (score 2):

just run **pub get** in your main pubspec.yaml file

Answer (score 1):

removing .dart_tool folder in all modules (if you have more than one) helped me
[image]

Comment: and dont forget to flutter clean / flutter pub get, could help too

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as you. In my case, I have 2 modules (package namely `core` and `shared`). In `shared` modules I add a new package like `shimmer` and `cached_network_image` for creating a custom widget. Also, I can `import` and use that package that I already added in `shared` modules. But after I running the project, I get the error with information like `Could not resolved the package ...`. So to fix it, I just add `shimmer` and `cached_network_image` package into my root project. So for this, I already add `2x` package. In `shared` modules and in the root project. So I think you should do it too if getting that error.

In my case, that requires 2x add new package into pubspec.yml are `json_serializable`, `shimmer`, `cached_network_image`

> Not all of it has to be added twice, only those that cause errors are added.

Answer (score 0):

Clean up the cache by `flutter pub cache clean`

Run pub get for all packages `flutter update-packages`

Answer (score -2):

remove .idea folder from your project and restart android studio works fine for me

Answer (score -3):

Installing the [`characters` package](https://pub.dev/packages/characters) solved my problem.